# Debugging x64 with SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf

I use SQLite in the project

I tested:

- `System.Data.SQLite.x64`
- `System.Data.SQLite`

The error shows up when I want to debug in x64
This is necessary because I'm using an external DLL in x64 (`DllImport`)

```
SQLite error (1): no such table: MAIN in "SELECT ID FROM MAIN"
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code
SQL logic error
no such table: MAIN
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your query to:

```
SELECT ID FROM [DatabaseName]..MAIN
```

Is the error occurring only when you're debugging?

Comment: This is not a problem here. When I set `Any CPU`, the database works but then the DLL does not work

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

It sounds like you're loading the wrong version of the DLL, I've had problems like this myself in the past. Make sure you're checking at runtime whether you're running in 32 or 64 bit mode and then loading the appropriate DLL. Better yet, run NuGet Manager and add SQLite to your project from there, that version supports both.